# Javascript flash card script how can I get it to toggle?

Tags: javascript, toggle, accordion

I tweaked a an accordion script to get a light flash card script. It meets my needs the only problem is when I toggle down the item to see the answer and click on next it shows the next item with the answer. I tried to get my function to autmatically toggle the item back up but it doesn't work. Here is my page

```
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js">  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('#accordion').find('#accordion-toggle').click(function(){

//Expand or collapse this panel
$(this).next().slideToggle('fast');



//Hide the other panels
//$("#accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

});
});
</script>

<style>
#accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer; margin: 0; font-size:22; }
#accordion-content {display: none;font-size:22; }
#accordion-content.default {display: block;}
#accordion {align: center; text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion" >
<h3>Click on next or previous to see the idioms in English. Click on the    
idiom to see the equivalent in French</h1>
<br>
<h4 id="accordion-toggle"></h4>
<div id="accordion-content">
    <p></p>
</div>

<div align="center">
<br>
<button onclick="myFunctionNext()">Previous</button>
<button onclick="myPrevious()">Next</button>
</div>
<script>
var idioms = ["Once bitten twice shy", "Chat échaudé craint l'eau froide",     
"Drive a hard bargain","Etre dur en affaires","To bone up","Bachoter","It  
takes all sorts to make a world","Il faut de tout pour faire un monde", 
"Chasing shadows", "Lacher la proie pour l'ombre", "To run out of   
steam","Etre à bout de souffle"];
var a = 0;
function myFunctionNext() {

myVar="Hello world";
a=a+2;
if( a>idioms.length-1){
a=a-idioms.length;}
var idiomen = idioms[a];
var idiomfr = idioms[a+1];
document.getElementById("accordion-toggle").innerHTML = idiomen;
document.getElementById("accordion-content").innerHTML = idiomfr;





}

function myPrevious() {
a=a-2
if( a>idioms.length-1){
a=a-idioms.length;}
if( a<0){
a=a+idioms.length;}
var idiomen = idioms[a];
var idiomfr = idioms[a+1];
document.getElementById("accordion-toggle").innerHTML = idiomen;
document.getElementById("accordion-content").innerHTML = idiomfr;



}

</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/zardax/0Lsaonfv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *so* difficult to read your code due to the fact that it is unformatted. I urge you to start using indentation and whitespace; making your code more readable will make it easier to understand.

The solution to your problem is that you need to slideUp the `#accordion-content` element in each of your `myFunctionNext` and `myPrevious` click handlers. In order to have the idiom change *after* the content has finished collapsing, you should take the existing function bodies and put them in a callback to `slideUp`. The result would be:

```
function myFunctionNext () {
    $('#accordion-content').slideUp(function () {
        // existing myFunctionNext body goes here.
    });
}

function myPrevious () {
    $('#accordion-content').slideUp(function () {
        // existing myPrevious body goes here.
    });
}
```

Now that we have it working, we can set our minds to refactoring. I think your code can be improved a great deal.

We can help ourselves by giving better names to our variables. "a" is a terrible name for an index; and our methods should not be prefixed with "my". We can cache our `#accordion-toggle` and `#accordion-content` elements for efficiency. Finally, let's break-up our methods and give them descriptive names to help clarify what our code is doing.

The refactored JavaScript would be:

```
var idioms = [
    "Once bitten twice shy",
    "Chat échaudé craint l'eau froide",
    "Drive a hard bargain",
    "Etre dur en affaires",
    "To bone up","Bachoter",
    "It takes all sorts to make a world",
    "Il faut de tout pour faire un monde",
    "Chasing shadows",
    "Lacher la proie pour l'ombre",
    "To run out of steam",
    "Etre à bout de souffle"
];

var index = 0;
var increment = 2;
var $accordion_toggle = $('#accordion-toggle');
var $accordion_content = $('#accordion-content');

function incrementIndex () {
    index += increment;

    if (index >= idioms.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
}

function decrementIndex () {
    index -= increment;

    if (index < 0) {
        index = (idioms.length - increment);
    }
}

function updateIdioms () {
    $accordion_toggle.html(idioms[index]);
    $accordion_content.html(idioms[index + 1]);
}

function onNextClick () {   
    $accordion_content.slideUp(function () {
        incrementIndex();
        updateIdioms();
    });
}

function onPreviousClick () {
    $accordion_content.slideUp(function () {
        decrementIndex();
        updateIdioms();
    });
}

$(function () {
    updateIdioms();

    $('#Next').click(onNextClick);
    $('#Previous').click(onPreviousClick);

    $accordion_toggle.click(function () {
        $accordion_content.slideToggle('fast'); 
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/0Lsaonfv/4/